# How to 'Disable submit button after clicking it'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

I have a page which has a form. When I click the submit button, I need to display a message prompt if continue submit or not. If the user clicks continue submit, I need to disable the submit button while the page is submitting.

The code below does not work.

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">

<button type="submit" id="subbutton" name="submit_page[]" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure of your choices?'); this.disabled=true;">Submit </button>

</form>
```

The code below is from my action_page.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_page'])){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the **pointer-events** and **opacity** accordingly:

```
#subbutton {
    "pointer-events" : "none", 
    "opacity" : 0.5
}
```

To **reenable** the button:

```
#subbutton {
    "pointer-events" : "auto", 
    "opacity" : 1
}
```

Using **JavaScript**:

```
function set_submit(type) {
    if(type == 'disable') {
        document.getElementById('divsubbutton').style.pointerEvents = "none";
        document.getElementById('divsubbutton').style.opacity = 0.5;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('divsubbutton').style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        document.getElementById('divsubbutton').style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
```

**Use as needed**:

```
set_submit('disable')
set_submit('enable')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to preceding `return` statement which interrupts the *onclick* function prior reaching `this.disabled=true`; Simply remove the statement keyword `return`.

```
 < ... onclick="confirm('Are you sure of your choices?'); this.disabled = true;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I tried this. It disabled the button but I never reached action_page.php

Answer (score 0):

I would define a function to handle the submit and disable the button. In fact, if you disable the button when it's clicked, the form won't be submitted; so you need to disable the submit button only after submission happens (i.e. within `onsubmit` event)

```
function onSubmit() {
    document.getElementById("subbutton").disabled = true; 
}
```

your html will look like:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return onSubmit()">

    <button type="submit" id="subbutton" name="submit_page[]" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure of your choices?');">Submit </button>

</form>
```

Comment: I tried this one. My button was disabled, but I noticed that the submit process was so fast and the action_page.php was not reached.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple - just add an `if` statement:

```
<button type="submit" id="subbutton" name="submit_page[]" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure of your choices?')) this.disabled = 'disabled'">Submit </button>
```

Comment: My form did not submit. It just disabled my button.